# Delete all words in the current line and leave it a blank line in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode, we can use a shortcut to delete the current line. But sometimes I want to rewrite the current line, so I don't want to delete the line when we are deleting all the words. Is there any way to delete all words but don't delete the current line?

Answer (score 10):

There is a useful command `deleteAllLeft` and `deleteAllRight` which are unbound by default.  So try in your `keybindings.json`:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+backspace",
  "command": "deleteAllLeft"
}
```

It will delete any indentation on the left as well  - until your formatter kicks in however you have it set up.

Comment: If you normally develop on OSX and use cmd + backspace to remove the entire contents of a line rather than just a single word (like how most windows program work) this is the command that results in similar functionality.

Comment: This works great, only thing missing is keeping indentation.

Answer (score 5):

I looked through [*Keyboard Shortcuts*](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) of VS Code, it doesn't have such thing as deleting contents of a line and leaving the empty line.

You can use one of the following combinations:

1. <kbd>Home</kbd> then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> (or <kbd>End</kbd> then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>) to select the contents, then <kbd>Delete</kbd> or start typing (as you want to rewrite the line)
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to delete line, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to insert new line above. This will move the cursor to the empty line so you can start typing the new content.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way is <kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>Del</kbd> ,
but **delete** the current line

Answer (score 1):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the line you want to delete and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>. This will delete the entire line.
2. Place the cursor at the end of the line you want to delete and press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>. This will delete all the text to the left of the cursor.